# Create new instance from Moq.object failed unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I am trying to instantiate a new object using the moq that I have set up but I am not getting the data I've set up in moq. Why?

For instance: I've set up `MyMethod()` to `true` in mock. But when I create the new instance from `mock.object` I am getting `false` for `MyMethod()`.

**Interface:**

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    bool MyMethod();
}
```

**Class**

```
 public class MyClass : IMyClass
    {
        public MyClass(IMyClass myClass)
        {

        }

        public bool MyMethod()
        {
            return false;
        }

        public string DoSomething()
        {
            if(MyMethod() == false)
            {
                // do something
                return "did something";
            }
            else
            {
                // do something else
                return "did something else";
            }
        }
    }
```

**TestMethod**

```
   [TestMethod]
        public void MyMethodTest()
        {
            var moq = new Mock<IMyClass>();
            moq.Setup(m => m.MyMethod()).Returns(true);

            var sut = new MyClass(moq.Object);
            Assert.AreEqual(sut.DoSomething(), "did something else"); // Actual: "did something" Expected: "did something else"
        }
```

Comment: It fails because you are not assigning any value in the class to the public member being compared.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with that test. It is difficult to determine what behavior the test is actually trying to assert

Comment: @Nkosi I am trying to mock MyMethod to return something based on some other properties. But to prove that it doesn't work as I would expected so I choose to use a simple example of mocking a property.

Comment: You inject the interface but do not use it within the class> IT may be that you have simplified the example too much. Can you update the question with the actual details of what you are testing so we can provide you with the relevant details you seek.

Comment: Can you give an example how to use it in the class?

Comment: For clarification. Is it that you want the class to wrap the interface

Comment: I've updated my unit test to clearify what I meant to achieve.

Comment: Are you following a pattern that requires your class which inherits an interface to depend on that same interface?

Comment: `public MyClass(IMyClass myClass) {}`. Your `sut` instance is being created, passing your mock object into the instance, and then **you do nothing with the mock instance**. That's the problem. You need to capture the mock instance in a private field and then call the methods on the mock object. Part of the confusion may be stemming from you creating a mock of the class you're testing. You don't mock the thing you're testing, you mock the *dependencies being used by the thing you're testing*.

Answer (score 0):

The test fails because you are not assigning any value in the class to the public member being compared.

`MyClass.MyProperty` is never assigned a value, so in

```
Assert.AreEqual(sut.MyMethod(), true);
```

`sut.MyMethod()` will be `false`

You would need to refactor the class to use the value from the injected interface and assign it to the respective member.

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass {
    public bool MyProperty { get; set; }

    public bool MyMethod() {
        return MyProperty;
    }
    
    public MyClass(IMyClass myClass) {
        this.MyProperty = myClass.MyProperty; // assigning value to property
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work for the properties and fields level. How can I achieve the same for mocking a method? I've updated my unit test to take mocking a method into acount.

Comment: @CB4 The same would apply to the method. You class is not using the interface's method anywhere. Is the class using the property or the method from the interface? You still not clear on what it is you are doing.

Comment: I want to use the method from the class. But I want to mock the return for that method.

Comment: @CB4 understood but how does the interface  affect that.

Comment: @CB4 I strongly suggest you update the post with the actual code being used. Your example a too simple and will only cause more confusion in providing you with an answer.

Comment: I've updated the code